# python skia save skia.DynamicMemoryWStream to svg file

Tags: python, svg, skia

in short, the following code can give the context:

```
import skia
stream = skia.DynamicMemoryWStream()
...
```

There are more operations done over the `stream` variable, but they are not important and the key thing here is I want to convert the `stream` to an SVG file. I have looked Python skia library documentation, however, their documentation is poorly written and I wasn't able to find out a way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to solve it.
Say you have a variable `stream` which is contain the data and is `DynamicMemoryWStream` class,  then you first need to transfer the data into class `FileWStream`, then you use `FileWStream` to transfer the data into the svg file. To be more specific, do the following:

1. create an empty svg file, say name it `example.svg`
2. create stream to the file with following code

```
file_stream = skia.FILEWStream("example.svg")
```

3. write from stream to file stream

```
stream.writeToStream(file_stream)
```

4. Finally flush the file stream so it write all data received to the file

```
file_stream.flush()
```